# How do you install the PigPen plugin in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, apache-pig

I tried to install PigPen using the directions here:
http://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigPen

But despite rebooting Eclipse, it doesn't seem to recognize that I put a new jar in the plugins folder.

Comment: Did you specify the '-clean' option like the web page suggests?

Comment: I sure did! It didn't make a difference. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is dropins folder on the same level with plugins folder. Eclipse by default configured to pick up new plugins from it.

Comment: I just found the dropins folder last night when I installed Mars. I was running Luna. I'll have to check and see if Luna has a dropins folder. Thanks! I'm up and running.